# Use PersistentCookieStore globally

Tags: java, android, cookies, http-request

I have a PersistentCookieStore and I want to use it globally so it means It writes cookies into it in login.java, and I want to perform requests with theese cookies in mainactivity.java
How can I do this? Actually I declare the PCS like this:

```
PersistentCookieStore myCookieStore = new PersistentCookieStore(this);
client.setCookieStore(myCookieStore);
```

But I cant do this in both classes because then it would be new every time, or am I wrong? :o

Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're using [the `android-async-http`library](https://github.com/loopj/android-async-http/) then `PersistentCookieStore` is persistent so it stores any Cookies you add to it in Shared Preferences.  This means if you create instances of it in different Activities they will all have access to the same cookies.

In other words, if you write cookies to an instance of `PersistentCookieStore` in `Login.java` they will be available to a different instance of  `PersistentCookieStore` in `MainActivity.java`.